# NodeJS & Express Creating multiple dynamic servers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using nodeJS and Express to try and create multiple simple web services dynamically. I only have 2 small classes so far. Here is my main class, which is supposed to create N (this case 4) instances of the Service class.

```
    const Service = require('./service')

    serviceArr = new Array()
    var temp
    for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        temp = new Service(8080+i)
        serviceArr[i] = temp
    }

    console.log(serviceArr)
```

This is the service class which gets  "created" N times

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();


class Service { 
    constructor(inc){
    this.port = inc 
    this.data = inc 
    console.log('Service created on port: ' + this.port)
    app.listen(this.port)
    app.get('/heartbeat', (req, res) => {
        res.send(this.port.toString() + 'testing')
    })

}



}



module.exports = Service
```

I would like for the web service to just return the port number on which it is running. **I can access the web service from all the ports, however the port number which the service is meant to return is always 8080**. These are the console logs if it helps

```
Service created on port: 8080
Service created on port: 8081
Service created on port: 8082
Service created on port: 8083
[ Service { port: 8080, data: 8080 },
  Service { port: 8081, data: 8081 },
  Service { port: 8082, data: 8082 },
  Service { port: 8083, data: 8083 } ]
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: maybe you can have a look at nodejs clustering.  According to me it has all functionality you are trying to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only creating one express 'app' (the module containing the class `Service`)

Instead, create a new express 'app' every time Service is constructed.
Currently every port is sharing the same express app, and therefore the same `/heartbeat` endpoint code

```
var express = require("express");

class Service { 
    constructor(inc){
        this.port = inc;
        this.data = inc;
        var app = express();
        console.log('Service created on port: ' + this.port)
        app.listen(this.port)
        app.get('/heartbeat', (req, res) => {
            res.send(this.port.toString() + 'testing')
        })

    }
}


module.exports = Service
```

Comment: does the mutiple app created run on single thread or mutiple thread on different CPU core?

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `this` changes to a higher-level one as you're calling `this.port` inside the callback function.

By the way, as someone has already mentioned in the comments, you'd probably want to use the native cluster module or opt for a module such as `pm2` if you're looking for a clustered service. They should relieve you of some headache when it comes to that.